# Making local copy of git branch current

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket

I'm using new git tools (BitBucket, SourceTree) and only lightly familiar with git.

When I am at BitBucket (in the browser), there are two branches, master and 2.0.

I cloned the 2.0 branch locally and then I made rogersbranch off of that, where all of my changes have been made.

I didn't do whatever needs to be done to add rogersbranch to what BitBucket has.

Subsequently, someone else has made changes to the 2.0 branch.

What do I do to make my local copy current with what BitBucket has and merge the 2.0 commits into rogersbranch?

Thanks,

Roger

Comment: It depends on the workflow. Do you `rebase` your branch on master before merging it back?

Comment: I don't know. Except we're not changing master at all. All the work is on 2.0

Comment: Yes, my fault, just `git rebase 2.0` in your branch to synchronize with the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
git fetch
git checkout rogersbranch
git merge 2.0BranchName
```